# How to drive high voltage transistor with low voltage op amp?

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, voltage-regulator, darlington

I'm trying to drive a darlington pair with 24 V collector voltage with an low voltage op amp. I tried adding a PNP transistor so the op amp just have to drive that single transistor, but haven't had any luck.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3fG6Q.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

How can I drive the transistor with low voltage op amp? is it even possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've rearranged your circuit to overcome the basic problems in the original: -

[image]

- Purple box shows an NPN transistor and not a PNP
- Blue box gets rid of the diode (the NPN will act like the original diode)
- Red box is a reversal of the inputs to the op-amp to maintain correct negative feedback.

Previously your circuit would not have produced more than about 3 or 4 volts at the output due to the op-amp being unable to drive higher than 5 volts. Given that you had three transistors as emitter followers, the output level would be restricted by the upper output voltage that the op-amp could produce.

Now, the added NPN can be turned on or off by the op-amp well within its own power rails.

But, the next problem you will likely face is instability; because I've added gain into the feedback path (NPN as a common emitter), there is every chance that the circuit will become an oscillator at some highish frequency so you might need to add compensation around the op-amp like this: -

[image]

- In red is an added emitter resistor - choose a value that is no less than one tenth of the resistor connected to the NPN collector
- In red is a frequency compensation circuit that can reduce the open-loop gain and produce a a roll-off of no more than 6 dB per octave up to the unity gain point. This should ensure that the phase angle doesn't reach the oscillation point.

### Simulation circuit

I used Micro-cap 12 to to a basic simulation of the DC levels to see that it functions: -

[image]

It produces 10.011 volts on the output for a reference input (V4) of 2.5 volts. Ideally it would be 10.000 volts but the op-amp I chose is a bit basic (LM324) and it has a significant input offset voltage that adds an error. The load is 100 ohms (R6) and it is drawing 100 mA as expected.

I used a TIP120 Darlington for the main power transistor.

Now If I look at the transient plot I get this: -

[image]

In other words it's significantly unstable but, I chose R2 (emitter resistor) to be 100 ohms to purposefully entice it to be unstable - If I make R2 into 1 kohm I get this: -

[image]

It looks fairly stable but, if I add 1 uF output capacitance across the load this happens: -

[image]

Not so stable now is it. So, integrating feedback around the op-amp will probably help. 220 pF and 1 kohm added to turn bare op-amp into an integrator: -

[image]

It's just at the cusp of being stable so I'd go for something in excess of 1 nF to kill the problem off.

Comment: Thanks, can't it be done with negative feedback to get rid of the stability issues?

Comment: What appears to be negative feedback at DC and low frequencies, turns into positive frequencies at much higher frequencies. I'm countering that with negative feedback around the op-amp to lower its gain so that at higher frequencies it's gain is less than 1 hence it can't oscillate. Ditto with the emitter resistor - it is another form of negative feedback although you probably can't see that.

Comment: Last question; is there a down side in regulating voltage like that? asking that because all schematics I've seen of industrial/home-brew PSUs are using negative feedback.

Comment: It is using negative feedback; I swapped the op-amp input terminals because I changed the non-inverting PNP emitter follower stage into an inverting NPN common emitter stage.

Comment: Thanks for adding the simulation results, appreciate it.

Comment: @ElectronSurf you need to get hold of microcap - it's free now.

Comment: Downloaded it and now watching the tutorial, thanks again.

Comment: I couldn't get  that circuit to be stable, increasing R2 is causing the output unable to get down to 0V. I came up with another circuit, added the schematic to the question. please take a look at it.

Comment: @ElectronSurf looks OK but falstad is such an ugly simulator. Hey, one of your transistor in the Darlington pair is an PNP.

Comment: I know and it's reverse biased, and it's working in the falstad!!! that's why I asked you to take a look at it! is it simulator fault? I couldn't completely learn MC so I just did a quick test in falstad...

Comment: Well, you have really followed my circuit have you? I can't go around checking every different permutation cause there aint enough hours in the day. A 1 ohm load is a bit excessive.

Comment: I did played with it but since I don't know how to simulate using MC I couldn't really go in depth. I understand, just a general  opinion is all that ask.

Comment: I spent a lot of time showing you why you needed (A) and emitter resistor and (B) local integrating feedback around the op-amp. I'm not going to try and debug something that goes against what I recommend. I can't believe that you might expect me to!!!!!!

Comment: Got it, thanks.

Comment: In my circuit (the one I sent you), if you lower R3 to about 3 kohm, you might be able to drive a 20 amp load in a simulation but you would need a much more robust output Darlington transistor. Beyond the scope of this question. If you have to use Falstad, use my circuit.

Comment: The emitter resistor R2 is raising the ground making the output higher than 0V when the op amp input is 0V.

Comment: I think this needs a new question because it can't be solved in comments. Show the circuit that causes this problem in that question. I'm closing down for tonight now so maybe someone else will provide an answer.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109615/discussion-on-answer-by-andy-aka-how-to-drive-high-voltage-transistor-with-low-v).

Answer (score 0):

If i'm understanding it right, you want the Opamp to control the flow of the voltage throught your darlington pair?

So far there's some things, that needs to be changed.
The diode i blocking the voltage coming from your opamp, so your transistor never opens.
When you use a PNP transistor, because of the flow throughout the transistor, you need the darlington pair to be connected to the collector of your PNP transistor.

Darlington pair also has a common collector, so i'm not sure you can connect it like that.